# How can edit the value of Html.TextBoxFor in controller before use it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.textboxfor

I'm working on my project in MVC 3 and searching for a way, which can add this functionality to all my Html.TextboxFor:
When user type "foo" and submit form, in controller level I get it by model as "fuu" for example.

I need this feature to replace some Unicode characters by some others.

Let I show my code in View and Controller:

View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title) // user will type "foo", in TitleTexbox!
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult Create(MyModel model)
    {
     var x = model.Title;
     //I need variable x have 'fuu' instead of 'foo', replaceing "o" by "u"
     //...
    }
```

Should I write an override for Html.TextboxFor?

Comment: can you make your question more clear?

Comment: I have some views. each view has some textbox. Before MVC, I had a method which correct my input text, then save it in db. for example I want to replace all 'a' by 'b'. simply I call that method every time I use the text of inputs. Now in MVC, I'm searching for a  generic way, which apply to all Html.TextboxFor in views.

Comment: the method you want to be generic can not be specific to a view item (e.g: TextBoxFor) .but it can be specific to a "model" or "view model".

Comment: if what you want to do is making changes to data posted from client and then storing it in the db.you can use custom model binding for particular type.

Comment: yes, you are right! I need making changes to the posted data from client and then storing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i understood from your code , you expect from your model to be ready(processed) when it passed to your controller action.and for accomplishing this the only way is using model-binding.
but this approach is limited to particular type/class/model/viewmodel or whatever you name it.

you can create your own modelBinder as:

```
 public class MyCustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
          public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) 
          {
              var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
              var myModel= (MyModel ) base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext) ?? new MyModel ();

              myModel.Title.Replace('o','u');

              return myModel;
         }
    }
```

and then you most register your Custom Model Binder in Global.asax

```
  ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(MyModel),new MyCustomModelBinder());
```

make change in your action like this:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult Create([ModelBinder(typeof(MyCustomModelBinder))] MyModel model)
    {
     var x = model.Title;
     //here you will have the modified version of your model 
     //...
    }
```

good luck.